# How to make a function which checks, if the labels of discriminated unions match?

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

Let's say we've got a uniontype in F#:

```
type Example =
    |FirstLabel of int
    |SecondLabel of int
    |ThirdLabel of int
```

How could you create a function, which takes 2 parameters of the type "Example" and returns true, if the two parameters share the same label and else returns false? I want this function to return these results regardless of the value of the integers.

So if we have parameter1 and parameter2 with

```
val parameter1 : Example = SecondLabel 2
```

and

```
val parameter2 : Example = Secondlabel 5
```

the function would return `true`

I could not find an answer for this question even by searching thoroughly. Maybe I searched wrongly. So could you also give me a source for solving such problems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
let sameLabels x y = 
    match x, y with
    | FirstLabel _ , FirstLabel _
    | SecondLabel _, SecondLabel _
    | ThirdLabel _ , ThirdLabel _  -> true
    | _ -> false
```